# Is there a way to capture "div" elements with selenium on an infinite-scroll website?

Tags: java, selenium

So I'm trying to make a program that when it's given credentials of an instagram account and an account name is going to like all pictures of the given account with the logged in account. Now every row of pictures on the instagram website is a separate div. It works well when one doesn't have more then 4 rows of pictures, but beyond that point when scrolling down new div's get "downloaded" and others dissapear. I'm trying to get all div elements in an ArrayList of WebElements so the program can easily go ahead and like everything when all div's are added in the list. The code for grabbing the WebElements right now is this:

```
public void readLines () {
    this.rijen = this.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div._2z6nI > article > div > div > div"));
}
```

I would love to find a possible solution but i couldn't find it somewhere else. Thank u guys in advance.

Comment: I know there is a similar, if not duplicate question around here. You need to scroll down the page and allow the pictures to auto load as you scroll.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I'll take a look.